# number of zeros of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the number of zeros of the holomorphic function
$ f (z) = e ^ {z + 3} + z ^ 3 + z ^ 2 + z + 1 $

in the unitary disk.

Anyone know how this exercise is solved?

Comment: Do you have a thought to share about this problem?  How to approach it,  what importance it has, where you encountered the problem?

Comment: I must certainly consider | z | = 1 because I have to focus on the drive disk.
I think I should apply Rouchè's theorem which allows me to count the zeros of a holomorphic function but I don't know how

Comment: unitary disk sorry

Comment: I would like to prove that $| f (z) - g (z) | <| f (z) |$ where $f (z) = e ^ {z + 3}$ e $g (z) = z ^ 3 + z ^ 2 + z + 1$

Comment: I'm going to suggest you edit that material in your Comments into the body of your Question. However it is confusing to redefine $f(z)$ the way you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be as you defined and $g$ equal $e^{z+3}$ then on the boundary of the unit disk you have $|f-g|<|g|$. Thus by [Rouché theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RouchesTheorem.html) $f$ has the same number of zeros as $g$, namely none inside the disk.

Comment: $|f-g| = |z^3+z^2+z+1| \leq 4$ ...  wthy $ 4 < |g| $?

Comment: @MartinaTrapasso: At worst $g=e^2$ which is greater than $4$.